# How does model.weights in tensorflow/keras work?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a model trained.
summary is as follows

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 256)               2560      
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 128)               32896     
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 35,585
Trainable params: 35,585
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And have weights

```
for i,weight in enumerate(Model.weights):
    exec('w{}=np.array(weight)'.format(i))
```

have test data for predict
 `x=test_data.iloc[0]`

then I predict with model
`Model.predict(np.array(x).reshape(1,9))`
get `array([[226241.66]], dtype=float32)`

then I predict with weights
`((x@w0+w1)@w2+w3)@w4+w5`
get `array([98039.99664026])`

Can someone explain how the weights in model works?

And how to get the model-predict result with weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Model.layers` which will return a list of all layers in your model, each layer has a function [`get_weights()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#get_weights) which will return the weights as numpy arrays. I was able to reproduce the output of a simple 3 layer feed-forward model with this approach.

```py
for i,layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    exec('w{}=np.array(layer.get_weights()[0])'.format(i)) # weight
    exec('b{}=np.array(layer.get_weights()[1])'.format(i)) # bias

X = np.random.randn(1,9)
np.allclose(((X@w1[0] + b1[1])@w2[0] + b2[1])@w4[0] + b4[1], model.predict(X)) # True
```

Note: In my examle layer 0 was a input layer (no weights) and layer 3 a dropout layer (no weights). When calling `model.predict()`, dropout is not applied, therefore you can ignore it in this case.